# Cannot pass user input to nlme() function

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a shiny app and right now I am in need of a nlme function sumarry. For the model= requirement in the function I want to use the users input, however it just reads input and tries to look for that object in the dataframe, how do I fix that problem?

Users input in ui:

```
h5(helpText("Provide the variable that varies with time")),
selectInput(inputId = "vartime", label = "Variable that varies with time", choices=c(), selected=""),
h5(helpText("Provide the identification variable")),
selectInput(inputId = "id", label = "Variable name", choices=c(), selected=""),
actionButton("numAdd","Add"),
```

Output in ui:

```
verbatimTextOutput("ModelSumarry")
```

My method for the nlme function in server:

```
Model <- eventReactive(input$numAdd, {
    validate(
      need((!is.null(mydata())), "No datafile found")
    )
    Data <- mydata()
    
    #inputs not working 
    nlme <- nlme(input$vartime ~ beta_1 + d_1i,
                          data=Data,
                          fixed=beta_1~1,
                          random=d_1i~1,
                          group=~input$id,
                          start=c(beta_1=input$num),
                          na.action="na.omit")
    summary(nlme)
  })
  
  output$ModelSumarry <- renderPrint({
    Model()
  })
```

I know the function works, because when you provide an actual variable from the data frame it works, but I need it to be the users input.

input$num, does not cause any problems.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: you need to use `as.formula()` or `reformulate()` to construct your main formula and your groups formula

Comment: Would it be possible to show me how to use them? I have tried both methods, the only one that worked was `reformulate(c("beta_1", "d_1i"),input$vartime)` but then I got way different numbers than just providing variable names i know exist in the dataframe. Still could not change input$id.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regression in shinyApp with dynamic variable selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70224140/regression-in-shinyapp-with-dynamic-variable-selection)